# Compiling Kivy application to Windows Executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, pyinstaller

I have been fighting PyInstaller for the past week trying to get my application to compile into a single executable.

I've tried several different implementations with the .spec file, and of the many methods I try, I can either get it to compile into a single executable that crashes immediately on launch, doesn't launch at all, or it runs, but is extremely slow. Nothing compared to that of when I run it out of PyCharm.

I'm unsure if the slow run speeds is because of the compiler or what, but it takes roughly 1-2 seconds for the execution task to run when I run it through PyCharm, however when it is ran from the executable it takes about 30-35 seconds and the application hangs.

My application essentially takes some text from TextInput boxes, grabs the text values from them, does some SQL querying and then submits proper information to update / add entry information into an access database.

My latest .spec file is as follows:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

import pyodbc

from datetime                   import date
from kivy.app                   import App
from kivy.uix.button            import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout         import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label             import Label
from kivy.uix.popup             import Popup
from kivy.uix.textinput         import TextInput
from kivy.lang                  import Builder
from kivy.properties            import BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['DBInterfaceAssistant.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Python36-32'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='DBInterfaceAssistant',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False )
```

The product of this is an application that doesn't launch, it attempts to load the application but crashes immediately.

---EDIT---

My Current build script is as follows:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

import pyodbc

from datetime                   import date
from kivy.app                   import App
from kivy.uix.button            import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout         import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label             import Label
from kivy.uix.popup             import Popup
from kivy.uix.textinput         import TextInput
from kivy.lang                  import Builder
from kivy.properties            import BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew
from kivy.tools.packaging.pyinstaller_hooks import get_deps_minimal, get_deps_all, hookspath, runtime_hooks

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['DBInterfaceAssistant.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Python36-32'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hookspath=hookspath(),
             runtime_hooks=runtime_hooks(),
             ** get_deps_all())
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
          name='DBInterfaceAssistant',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the example from the **Kivy** docs:

```
from kivy.tools.packaging.pyinstaller_hooks import get_deps_minimal, get_deps_all, hookspath, runtime_hooks
a = Analysis(['examples-path\\demo\\touchtracer\\main.py'],
         ...
         hookspath=hookspath(),
         runtime_hooks=runtime_hooks(),
         ...
         **get_deps_all())

coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('examples-path\\demo\\touchtracer\\'),
           a.binaries,
           a.zipfiles,
           a.datas,
           *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
           strip=False,
           upx=True,
           name='touchtracer')
```

https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-windows.html#overwrite-win-hook

Comment: So, with this executable, I need it to be one file. The example that PyInstaller provides doesn't format it to be a onefile package. 

I have tried using this method, and it works, but because of some network security restrictions the directory output is not acceptable.

Comment: can you update the question with your current build script?

Comment: Updated. Sorry, I've been rather busy today.

Comment: You are still missing the hookspath/runtime_hooks/get_deps_all part... in `Analysis `

Comment: After compiling it using the noted options, the program runs. However, when executing the intended feature of the application it errors out and states:
"Fatal Error: Failed to execute script DBInterfaceAssistant."

Comment: For whatever reason, I recompiled using the same properties in the spec, and it works. It occasionally hangs, but I can't be sure why that is. It doesn't do it when it's not compiled into one file. It may be a limitation of the pyinstaller compiler. Appreciate your help.